# Effect of treatment on correlation between two sets of variables

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho

Imagine I wish to see the effect of some treatment on the correlation between two groups of variables, which I measure with Spearman's rank correlation coefficient.

Treatment A gives a Spearman's rank of 0.4, 0.44, 0.43 for my 3 replicates.

Treatment B gives a Spearman's rank of 0.48, 0.45, 0.46 for my 3 replicates

Treatment C gives a Spearman's rank of 0.47, 0.50, 0.51 for my 3 replicates.

Can I compare the groups using e.g. the Mann-Whitney U test?

N.B. I'm not looking for the correlation between the sets of variables, I'm looking to see whether a specific treatment improves the correlation.

Apologies if this question is similar to this [Significance test on the difference of Spearman's correlation coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17696/significance-test-on-the-difference-of-spearmans-correlation-coefficient)

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible to test if two Pearson product-moment correlations are equivalent.  The most basic approach is to use a t-test.  This assumes that the distribution of the sample statistic is approximately normal under the [Fisher transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation).  Dividing the difference of the two transformed values by the standard error of the difference (which is: $\sqrt{1/(N_1-3)+1/(N_2-3)}$) constitutes a valid t-test used like any other.  ([Here](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/09/significance-tests-on-correlations.html) is a good, basic overview of tests of correlations by one of CV's esteemed contributors.)  However, I don't know if the Fisher transform of Spearman's rho is normally distributed.  Hence, your suggestion of the Mann-Whitney U test is reasonable.  However, since you have more than 2 groups, the [Kruskal-Wallis test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) is more appropriate, as 3 pairwise comparisons leads to a [multiplicity problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons).

Comment: OK, so I suppose the Mann-Whitney U would not be affected by scaling, since the ranks would remain the same.

Comment: Can I pair the data with the Kruskal Wallis test? I.e. pair (well I suppose group is better than pair for 3 samples) the 0.4, 0.48 and 0.47