# Cor.test and statistical test values for spearman correlation, how to make sense of them?

Tags: r, spearman-rho

I am trying to make sense of the spearman test I am getting as a result of using [cor.test on R package](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cor.test.html). [This page](http://geography.uoregon.edu/geogr/topics/interpstats.htm) seemed to me to inform that I should care not only for p-values and rho values from the output but as well its relation with the t tests. Sometimes I get as result p value of 0 and rho value of 1 and the value of the statistical test is zero as well.

I saw a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17696/significance-test-on-the-difference-of-spearmans-correlation-coefficient) but seems too focused on some performed spearman correlation. Since this is not really R related but involves conceptual understanding of spearman test statistic as mentioned on R, I thought this would be more appropriated than stack overflow.

Thank you.

Comment: Fun how you share the same question and the same surname, and the same country lol :)

Not yet, I had an statistician tell me that they should be cross-sectional but not enough details for me to reason over it. So the question still remains.